# What kind of library contents dumpbin as neither symbols or exports?

Tags: windows, visual-c++, libraries, portable-executable, dumpbin

Generally speaking, `dumpbin /symbols` shows the symbols exported from a static library, and `dumpbin /exports` shows the symbols exported from a dynamic library.

I have encountered a library that doesn't show up as either:

```
(c1) C:\Python-3.10.4\PCbuild\amd64>dumpbin /symbols liblzma.lib
Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 14.31.31104.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


Dump of file liblzma.lib

File Type: LIBRARY

(c1) C:\Python-3.10.4\PCbuild\amd64>dumpbin /exports liblzma.lib
Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 14.31.31104.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


Dump of file liblzma.lib

File Type: LIBRARY
```

So far, it looks empty, but it's not:

```
(c1) C:\Python-3.10.4\PCbuild\amd64>dumpbin /all liblzma.lib
Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 14.31.31104.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


Dump of file liblzma.lib

File Type: LIBRARY

Archive member name at 8: /
62937EFF time/date Sun May 29 15:11:11 2022
         uid
         gid
       0 mode
    147C size
correct header end

    203 public symbols

     3DFE lzma_simple_x86_decoder_init
     3DFE lzma_simple_x86_encoder_init
    120A0 lzma_simple_sparc_decoder_init
    120A0 lzma_simple_sparc_encoder_init
    1FB6A lzma_simple_props_encode
    1FB6A lzma_simple_props_size
    2CD9E lzma_simple_props_decode
    3A070 lzma_simple_coder_init
    49578 lzma_simple_powerpc_decoder_init
    49578 lzma_simple_powerpc_encoder_init
    ...
```

So it has plenty of contents, that are showing up as... what is going on here? What kind of library is this? How should the above output be interpreted?

Comment: How did you build or acquire `liblzma.lib` ?

Comment: @Dai By building Python 3.10.4 from source.

Comment: Just a static link library.  Without debugging symbols, use the /linkermember option to get the list you want to see.